# Where to move money in 401k to reduce risk?

Tags: united-states, 401k, bonds

I have a 401k where about 75% consists of stock based mutual funds. I want to use the remaining 25% to help protect what I've earned, especially in case the stock market goes down significantly. To do so, would I be correct in moving some money into bonds, like PIMCO Total Return?

Comment: Where is the remaining 25% currently allocated.

Comment: Bonds (and bond funds) are just less "risky" than (don't move _as much_ as) equities, but still tend to move in the same _direction_. So bonds will not necessarily "protect" the other 25% in a market crash - they just won't drop _as much_. Is that what you're looking for, or do you want something that will _gain_ in bear markets?

Comment: Related question: [Long Term Cash-Equivalent ETFs for “cash” allocation](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2806/long-term-cash-equivalent-etfs-for-cash-allocation).

Comment: @RonJon - currently in PIMCO total return

Comment: @D Stanley - if there's an option to gain in a bear market, I'd be interested in learning more.

Comment: @Craig: There are bear-market funds that are designed to rise when the market falls.  They can be used to hedge risk but can be somewhat hair-raising for a long-term portfolio, as they tend to fall when the market rises, and in general the market tends to rise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bonds are typically less volatile than equities (rising slower, crashing less and rebounding quicker).  However, the value of PTTRX has dropped 9% in the past 5 years, while only yielding about 2.6%.

A good answer would really depend on what your 401(k) offers, and it's expenses.

Comment: Is there a more popular bond fund then PTTRX?